# Det, MatrixRank and Eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I consider myself to be an inexperienced *Mathematica* user so maybe someone could point out what am I doing wrong.

In short, here is what I want to get: suppose that there is a matrix of dimension $ N \times N $. I know that at least one of the eigenvalues should always be zero. What I need to determine is the maximum number of non-zero eigenvalues; no need for explicit ones. I found out that the function `MatrixRank` should do it. I came across one of the matrices, which seemed to "*violate*" the rule for eigenvalues, in the sense that I wasn't getting a zero eigenvalue. Later I was pointed out that determinant of the given matrix is "0".

Here comes the issue. 2 functions return different results for a matrix of dimension 3:

```
Simplify[Det[M]] ->  0 
MatrixRank[M]    ->  3
```

Due to the specific matrix being way too long, I include a [link to it](https://pastebin.com/sgvGatVT). This is the original matrix, I use `TrigToExp` afterwards as it seemed to reduce the computation process time. In both cases I got the same result for `Det` and `MatrixRank`.

P.S. I need a symbolic evaluation and am currently using *Mathematica* 11.1.1.0.

Comment: If one of the eigenvalues are 0, then the determinant is zero, because the determinant equals the product of all eigenvalues...

Comment: When Mathematica calculated the `MatrixRank` with symbolic entries, it gives the "most general"/"least specific" value of the rank. Maybe that is your issue...

Comment: Thank you for comments. I am still interested if it would be possible to determine amount of the non-zero eigenvalues without using numerical evaluation. Or maybe there are some other mathematical possibilities of doing that? In principle, this could be further reduced by hand, but I want a more or less to automate it as there are way more matrices.

Comment: Did you try NullSpace? Presumably this gives the dimension of the nullspace, which is the number of zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Are you sure of your Det calculation? I just tried with your 3x3 matrix and the det simplifies, but does not obviously equal zero. Perhaps you mean some specific values of the parameters? If so, please show these values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,@bills . `NullSpace` actually solves the issue. Well, to be honest it solves in some cases, so I guess I will perform double check using `MatrixRank`. And yes, I got that Det(M)=0 in _Mathematica_.

Comment: What's wrong with using a numerical method to determine the matrix rank?

Comment: @CarlWoll , it was my first assumption but randomly generating parameters for some reason didn't end up with correct eigenvalues, and yes, I was using `N[  ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a numerical method is acceptable, you can find the characteristic polynomial, and then find out how many coefficients are zero. Let `mat` be your matrix. Then:

```
coeff = CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, x], x];

SeedRandom[0];
With[{v = Reduce`FreeVariables @ mat},
    rules = Thread[v -> RandomReal[10, Length @ v, WorkingPrecision->50]]
];
coeff /. rules
```

> {0.*10^-45 + 0.*10^-45 I, -88.06869475049593825389409426950881792625734818 + 
>     0.*10^-46 I, 41.6148105746435957281515196867572568226297329616, 
>   -1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}

This shows that the matrix rank is at least 2 (only the constant term is zero).

Or, just use [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues):

```
Eigenvalues[mat /. rules]
Chop @ %
```

> {39.378334721261585770434684505881112377002680998 - 
>     8.9642095056061798556155811000294566716875029005*10^-58 I, 
>    2.23647585338200995771683518087614444562705196366 + 
>     5.0089274479735025489970467486450317946657226813*10^-58 I, 
>    2.48749661365029255751887504501496855632934665698*10^-60 - 
>     6.4330798253441844711669847353350620993805252084*10^-60 I}
>
> {39.378334721261585770434684505881112377002680998, 
>   2.23647585338200995771683518087614444562705196366, 0}

I think the characteristic polynomial approach is probably a bit more robust, since it avoids root finding.

Comment: `CharacteristicPolynomial` with approximate numeric input uses `Eigenvalues`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Did not know that. However, my use of `CharacteristicPolynomial` had exact input, so I don't think your comment is relevant?

Comment: If `mat` is exact then `CharacteristicPolynomial[mat]` will use different methods e.g. polynomial interpolation for integer/rational matrices (and that will be much faster than `Eigenvalues`).